# Как сделать, что бы при запуске программы получил сразу 4 значение, то есть код сработал при запуске 4 раза. Заранее спасибо

Tags: python

```
import hashlib
import json
import time

secret = "dsfdsf"
app_id = "sdfsdf"
nonce = str(time.time())
params_string = json.dumps(
    {"app_id": app_id, "nonce": nonce},
    separators=(',', ':')
)
sign = hashlib.md5((params_string + secret).encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
print(sign)
```

Comment: **Константин**, чтобы код работал несколько раз, его надо поместить в цикл, например, `for`. Или поясните, пожалуйста, более подробно, что вы хотите получить. Какой именно результат

Comment: @alex sign каждый раз имеет разное значение(из-за разного nonce), хочу что бы при запуске вышло сразу 4 значения

Comment: Вам нужно создать цикл из четырёх итераций. Начало цикла = `nonce`, конец цикла = `print( sign )`. Вы умеете создавать циклы ? Я сейчас уеду и вернусь часа через 3. Изучайте цикл `for`. ok ?

Comment: @alex, вайбы строгого родителя: "приду - проверю"

Comment: @insolor честно говоря, я забыл проверить )